# kafka.admin.TopicCommand Failing

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I am using a single node Kafka V 0.10.2 (16 GB RAM, 8 cores) and a single node zookeeper V  3.4.9 (4 GB RAM, 1 core ). I am having 64 consumer groups and 500 topics each having 250 partitions. I am able to execute the commands which require only Kafka broker and its running fine
ex.

> ./kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092
>   --describe --group

But when I execute the admin command like create topic, alter topic For example

> ./kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper :2181
>   --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic

Following exception is being displayed:

> Error while executing topic command : replication factor: 1 larger
>   than available brokers: 0 [2017-11-16 11:22:13,592] ERROR
>   org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidReplicationFactorException:
>   replication factor: 1 larger than available brokers: 0 
>   (kafka.admin.TopicCommand$)

I checked my broker is up. In server.log following warnings are there

```
[2017-11-16 11:14:26,959] WARN Client session timed out, have not heard from server in 15843ms for sessionid 0x15aa7f586e1c061 (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2017-11-16 11:14:28,795] WARN Unable to reconnect to ZooKeeper service, session 0x15aa7f586e1c061 has expired (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2017-11-16 11:21:46,055] WARN Unable to reconnect to ZooKeeper service, session 0x15aa7f586e1c067 has expired (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
```

Below mentioned is my Kafka server configuration :

```
broker.id=1
delete.topic.enable=true
num.network.threads=3
num.io.threads=8
socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.request.max.bytes=104857600
log.dirs=/kafka/data/logs
num.partitions=1
log.segment.bytes=1073741824
log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000
zookeeper.connect=<zookeeperIP>:2181
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=6000
```

Zookeeper Configuration is :

```
# The number of milliseconds of each tick
tickTime=2000
# The number of ticks that the initial
# synchronization phase can take
initLimit=10
# The number of ticks that can pass between
# sending a request and getting an acknowledgement
syncLimit=5
# the directory where the snapshot is stored.
# do not use /tmp for storage, /tmp here is just
# example sakes.
dataDir=/zookeeper/data
# the port at which the clients will connect
clientPort=2181
# the maximum number of client connections.
# increase this if you need to handle more clients
#maxClientCnxns=60
autopurge.snapRetainCount=20
# Purge task interval in hours
# Set to "0" to disable auto purge feature
autopurge.purgeInterval=48
```

I am not able to figure out which configuration to tune. What I am missing .Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: can u give me your zookeeper status?

Comment: @SHAKEELMOHAMMAD On running ./zkServer.sh status getting this following output
ZooKeeper JMX enabled by default
Using config: /zookeeper/zookeeper-3.4.9/bin/../conf/zoo.cfg
Mode: standalone

Comment: @SHAKEELMOHAMMAD When I was viewing previous kafka-server.log it was full with warning
WARN Attempting to send response via channel for which there is no open connection, connection id 2 (kafka.network.Processor)
How to resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are running consumer with zookeeper argument like

> ./kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper :2181 --replication-factor 1
>   --partitions 1 --topic

it means that consumer will go and ask zookeeper to about broker details. if broker details available in zookeeper it can able to connect to the broker.

in your scenario, I think zookeeper lost broker details. zookeeper usually store all your configuration in tree path.

to check whether zookeeper has broker path or not you need log into zookeeper shell using  `/bin/zkCli.sh -server localhost:2181`

after successful connection do `ls /` you will see output like this

```
[controller, controller_epoch, brokers, zookeeper, admin, isr_change_notification, consumers, config]
```

and then do `ls /brokers` output will be `[ids, topics, seqid]`

and then do `ls /brokers/ids` output will be `[0]` - it is an array of broker id's. if your array is empty `[]` that means that no broker details are present in your zookeeper

in that case, you need to restart your broker and zookeeper.

**Updated** :

This problem won't happen usually. because your zookeeper server is closing(killing) or losing broker path automatically.

To overcome this it is better to maintain two more zookeepers means complete 3 zookeepers nodes.

if it is local use localhost:2181, localhost:2182, localhost:2183.

if it is cluster use three instances zookeeper1:2181, zookeeper2:2181, zookeeper3:2181

**you can tolerate up to two failures.**

for creating topic and use following command :

> ./kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper
>   localhost:2181,localhost:2182,localhost:2183 --replication-factor 1
>   --partitions 1 --topic

Comment: Thanks for the explanation but what can I do to prevent such cases, Should I change or tune some configurations?